Disable autocomplete suggestion bar in utop
How can I disable the autocomplete suggestion bar in the utop OCaml toplevel?

Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

@Chris The bar changes each time I type a character, so I found it harder to focus on the line where I was typing input.

From man utop:

To  turn  off  utop's  advanced prompt features, add the following to init.ml
to turn off respectively (a) colors and the upper information line, and (b) the
lower boxed list of possible completions:

        #utop_prompt_dummy;;
        UTop.set_show_box false


Thus, I added UTop.set_show_box false;; to ~/.ocamlinit and the autocomplete suggestion bar was disabled.
